# Problem with the function "sum" and "mean" in r programming

Tags: r, sum, mean

I can not explain why the sum does not give zero

```
 > y
 -0.4300447  0.0377018  0.3923429
 > mean(y)
 3.701647e-17
 > sum(y)/3
 3.700743e-17
```

Comment: Related: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: floating point errors.. not specifically R-related, more computer-ralated..